# In java spring boot application , html does not load a function from the js file

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an html file in it a button that should call a function from the js file but it is not called.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/auth.js" th:inline="javascript"></script>

<button onclick="btnOpenModal()">open modal</button>


<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <p>FORM</p>
    <button>SUBMIT</button>
</dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
function btnOpenModal() {
    console.log("HELLO")
}
```

Files structure: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8eQs.png)

Exception: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el1px.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your static folder from static.js to static. Boot automatically recognizes static content in this folder. Secondly, use `th:src="@{/auth.js}"` to pull in your static js file. If your folder structure is really static/js then use `th:src="@{/js/auth.js}"`. It's tough to tell from your screen shot.

Comment: I have static/js/auth.js. But it still didn't work

Comment: In your browser, bring up developer tools and the network tab and report what the http status is of /js/auth.js.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CNRYQg3

Comment: Do you have Spring Security enabled? If so, add ```http.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()``` to your security configuration.